# Making an index sequence for tuple implementation

Tags: c++, tuples

Suppose I want to implement something like `std::tuple` myself, just the basics. I want to show a failed attempt first.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t I>
struct tuple_index_leaf {
    using Index = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
    std::size_t i = Index::value;
};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct tuple_index : tuple_index_leaf<Is>...
{};

template <std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto get_index(tuple_index<Is...> const &i) {
    return static_cast<const tuple_index_leaf<I>*>(&i)->i;
}

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct tuple_leaf : tuple_index_leaf<I> {
    T elem;
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct tuple : tuple_leaf<sizeof...(Ts), Ts>... {

};

template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts>
auto& get(tuple<Ts...> &t) {
    return static_cast<tuple_leaf<I, float>*>(&t)->elem;
}

int main() {
    tuple_index<0, 1, 2> ti;
    std::cout << get_index<0>(ti) << "\n";
    tuple<int, float> t;
    get<2>(t) = 3.14;
}
```

Now, take a look at `get` function. I hard coded the last type `float` and I can only call this with index 2, like `get<2>`. This is because the deficiency in my `tuple` constructor. If you look there, you will see that I am passing `sizeof...(Ts)` to `tuple_leaf`. For example, in this case, all my tuple leaves will be like `tuple_leaf<2, int>, tuple_leaf<2, float>`. What I wanted was an expansion like `tuple_leaf<0, int>, tuple_leaf<1, float>...`. The expansion I used, `tuple_leaf<sizeof...(Ts), Ts>...` does not give me these, I know. I need some sort of index sequence I figured and started implementing something like `tuple_index`. But that one requires me to pass `std::size_t...` and I don't know how to do that. So the question is, how can I get an expansion like `tuple_leaf<0, int>, tuple_leaf<1, float>...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not hard. Here is one example how to do this (not claiming the only one way, this was something I put together quickly):

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct tuple_leaf {
    T elem;
};

template<class SEQ, class... TYPE> struct tuple_impl;

template<size_t... Ix, class... TYPE>
struct tuple_impl<std::index_sequence<Ix...>, TYPE...> : tuple_leaf<Ix, TYPE>... { };

template<typename... Ts>
struct tuple : tuple_impl<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...> { };


// below lines are for testing
tuple<int, double, char*> tup;

// the fact that this compiles tells us char* has index 2
auto& z = static_cast<tuple_leaf<2, char*>&>(tup);
```

Comment: Thanks. But testing it, I realized we lose all type safety. Do you know why the program on following link compiles, where I assign `double` to `std::string`?  https://wandbox.org/permlink/uDBZAz5CqgeIhygW

Comment: @meguli this is a completely different question. `std::string k;   k = 3.14;` compiles. If you are unsure why, you should ask a separate question. Rest assured, no type safety is lost here.

Comment: Wow, it totally compiles. My bad, sorry!

Comment: Just a quick clarification, you pass an `index_sequence` to `tuple_impl` by `make_index_sequence` but the partial specialization with  `size_t ...Ix` is instantiated. I am having some trouble understanding exactly how that works. Could you explain?

Comment: @meguli not exactly sure what you are asking. The partial specialization will always be preferred over general template if it fits.

Comment: If I want to define a template like `template<size_t... Ix, class... TYPE>`, I get `parameter pack must be at the end` error. But looks like it is OK to define such a partial specialization. That part confuses me. We are passing an `index_sequence` for `SEQ` template parameter but partial specialization for `size_t... Ix` is chosen.

Comment: @meguli you are probably confused on how partial specialization works in general. You might want to ask a separate question with sufficient MCVE.